# revtex4 - AIP Review of Scientific Instruments template - Abstract does not have right-margin

Tags: compiling, revtex, journal-publishing, journal

I am writing a paper for AIP's RSI journal and am using their template (locater here: http://rsi.peerx-press.org/html/rsi/rsi_latex_template.html). In the output, the abstract does have a left margin (as it's supposed to) but does not have a right margin (which it should). Here is a portion of my code

```
%% ****** Start of file rsitemplate.tex ****** %
%%
%%   This file has been edited from the original source file.
%%   The original file is part of the revtex4-1 package indicated below.
%%   Version 4.1 of 9 October 2009.
%%
%
% This is a template for producing documents for use with 
% the REVTEX 4.1 document class and the RSI substyle.
% 
% Copy this file to another name and then work on that file.
% That way, you always have this original template file to use.

\documentclass[aip,rsi,reprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1} % for checking your page length
%\documentclass[aip,rsi,preprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1} % for review purposes
\usepackage{graphicx}

\draft % marks overfull lines with a black rule on the right

\begin{document}

% Use the \preprint command to place your local institutional report number 
% on the title page in preprint mode.
% Multiple \preprint commands are allowed.
%\preprint{}

\title{Capacitive-based dilatometer cell constructed of sapphire for measuring the thermal expansion of solids at low temperatures} %Title of paper

% repeat the \author .. \affiliation  etc. as needed
% \email, \thanks, \homepage, \altaffiliation all apply to the current author.
% Explanatory text should go in the []'s, 
% actual e-mail address or url should go in the {}'s for \email and \homepage.
% Please use the appropriate macro for the type of information

% \affiliation command applies to all authors since the last \affiliation command. 
% The \affiliation command should follow the other information.

\author{D. T. W. Buckingham}
%\email[]{dbuckingham@physics.montana.edu}
\author{J. J. Neumeier}
%\email{neumeier@physics.montana.edu}
%\homepage[]{Your web page}
%\thanks{}
%\altaffiliation{}
\affiliation{Department of Physics, Montana State University, P.O. Box 173840, Bozeman, Montana 59717-3840, USA}

% Collaboration name, if desired (requires use of superscriptaddress option in \documentclass). 
%\noaffiliation is required (may also be used with the \author command).
%\collaboration{}
%\noaffiliation

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}

% Abstract goes here.

A dilatometer cell that can detect sub angstrom changes in the length of solid specimens in the temperature range 0.3 K$<$\textit{T}$<$20 K, when used in conjunction with a Quantum Design Physical Properties Measurement System (PPMS\textsuperscript{\textregistered}), is described. It is constructed entirely from single crystal, c-axis oriented sapphire. This is a capacitive-based technique, where the spacing between two metalized plates allows detection of changes in length. It is also a relative measurement in the sense that the capacitor plate spacing is determined by the relative thermal expansions of the cell and sample. The advantage of using sapphire is that it has a very high thermal conductivity and electrical resistivity and a very low thermal expansion coefficient below 30 K. As a result, the dilatometer cell will obtain a fast thermal equilibrium with the surrounding atmosphere, remain electrically insulated from the capacitive electrodes and, for most measurements, have little contribution to the capacitance change. The construction and performance are described. Thermal expansion measurements on pure H$_2$O ice Ih single crystal specimens will also be presented.

\end{abstract}

\pacs{65.40.De}% insert suggested PACS numbers in braces on next line

\maketitle %\maketitle must follow title, authors, abstract and \pacs

% Body of paper goes here. Use proper sectioning commands.
% References should be done using the \cite and \label commands.
\section{Introduction}

This is the intro. It is very introductory. It is the best intro ever written in the world, a tribute.

\section{Experimental}
\subsection{Cell design, construction and assembly}

The dilatometer cell is composed of two T-shaped pieces, both with the same shape and dimensions as shown...

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file aiptemplate.tex ******
```

With the output:
[image: Sample .pdf output]

Is there something wrong that I am doing that's not creating a right-margin for the abstract or is it something wrong with the template?

Comment: AIP will convert your source file to their format anyway. I believe they use some forn of XML internally. This template is meant to give you a glimpse, how the final document will look like and will allow you to estimate the length. The exact formatting does for sure not affect peer review.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I kind of figured something along those lines, but I'd like to see it as it's intended so I can better judge the length of my paper (RSI has a 3 page limit)

Comment: I can't leave a comment because my rep is too low, but RSI only has the 3-page limit for notes. Regular articles can be any length. See here for what little extra detail there is: http://publishing.aip.org/authors/journal-guidelines

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same solution as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252045/4427

```
\documentclass[aip,rsi,reprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1} % for checking your page length
%\documentclass[aip,rsi,preprint,graphicx]{revtex4-1} % for review purposes
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%%% for patching abstract

%%% Patch \abstract so it uses the same margin on the right as on the left,
%%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252045 for the reasons
\makeatletter
\appto\abstract{%
  \let\latexlist\list \rightskip=\leftskip
  \def\list{\edef\keeprightskip{\the\rightskip}\latexlist}%
  \patchcmd\latexlist{\ignorespaces}{\rightskip\keeprightskip\ignorespaces}{}{}%
}
\makeatother
%%% End of patch

\begin{document}

\title{Capacitive-based dilatometer cell constructed of sapphire for 
       measuring the thermal expansion of solids at low temperatures}

\author{D. T. W. Buckingham}
\author{J. J. Neumeier}
\affiliation{Department of Physics, Montana State University, P.O. Box 173840, 
             Bozeman, Montana 59717-3840, USA}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
A dilatometer cell that can detect sub angstrom changes in the length of solid 
specimens in the temperature range 0.3 K$<$\textit{T}$<$20 K, when used in 
conjunction with a Quantum Design Physical Properties Measurement System 
(PPMS\textsuperscript{\textregistered}), is described. It is constructed 
entirely from single crystal, c-axis oriented sapphire. This is a capacitive-based 
technique, where the spacing between two metalized plates allows detection of 
changes in length. It is also a relative measurement in the sense that the 
capacitor plate spacing is determined by the relative thermal expansions of 
the cell and sample. The advantage of using sapphire is that it has a very high 
thermal conductivity and electrical resistivity and a very low thermal expansion 
coefficient below 30 K. As a result, the dilatometer cell will obtain a fast 
thermal equilibrium with the surrounding atmosphere, remain electrically insulated 
from the capacitive electrodes and, for most measurements, have little contribution 
to the capacitance change. The construction and performance are described. Thermal 
expansion measurements on pure H$_2$O ice Ih single crystal specimens will also 
be presented.
\begin{enumerate}
\item A dilatometer cell that can detect sub angstrom changes in the length of solid 
specimens in the temperature range 0.3 K$<$\textit{T}$<$20 K, when used in 
conjunction with a Quantum Design Physical Properties Measurement System 
(PPMS\textsuperscript{\textregistered}), is described.

\item A dilatometer cell that can detect sub angstrom changes in the length of solid 
specimens in the temperature range 0.3 K$<$\textit{T}$<$20 K, when used in 
conjunction with a Quantum Design Physical Properties Measurement System 
(PPMS\textsuperscript{\textregistered}), is described.
\end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}

\pacs{65.40.De}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is the intro. It is very introductory. It is the best intro ever 
written in the world, a tribute.

\section{Experimental}
\subsection{Cell design, construction and assembly}

The dilatometer cell is composed of two T-shaped pieces, both with the 
same shape and dimensions as shown...

\end{document}
```

I added an `enumerate` environment to show it works well; instead just adding `\rightskip=\leftskip` after `\begin{abstract}` doesn't.

Using a patch is better anyway because it doesn't change the syntax. The copy editors will be able to easily remove the patch in case they don't want it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{abstract}
\rightskip.5in
Your abstract...
\end{abstract}
```