# Width of structured abstract in revtex4-1

Tags: lists, margins, revtex, description, abstract

`revtex4-1` offers structured abstracts through a `description` environment inside an `abstract` environment. However, this messes up the right margin in `reprint` mode:

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
%       \begin{description}
%           \item[Introduction]
            \lipsum[1]
%       \end{description}
    \end{abstract}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the abstract is less wide than the two-column text, and centered. I consider this "correct". When uncommenting the three lines, the left margin remains the same, but on the right the text extends to the right margin of the two-column text. How can I fix this in a relatively general way (which ideally works for a range of society and journal options)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `revtex4-1` class commits a sin, mixing `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` with list environments. The same bad behavior happens with `enumerate` and `itemize`.

You can patch the definition of `\abstract` so that it patches `\list` and makes it respect the outer setting of `\rightskip`.

But my advice is to leave `revtex4-1` for submissions to journals that require it.

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\appto\abstract{%
  \let\latexlist\list
  \def\list{\edef\keeprightskip{\the\rightskip}\latexlist}%
  \patchcmd\latexlist{\ignorespaces}{\rightskip\keeprightskip\ignorespaces}{}{}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{A paper}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{description}
\item[Introduction] \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        \edef\oldrightskip{\the\rightskip} %thanks, egreg!
        \begin{description}
            \rightskip\oldrightskip\relax
            \item[Introduction]
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{description}
    \end{abstract}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```